# Jquery not Traversing with next() method

Tags: jquery

I have a click event handler thats adds a class of "active" to a body section when triggered.
the issue is that is if I click on the current button, it adds "active" to the next node instead of the current one. So the "active" class should alternate when the current button is clicked in each set.

```
$($contentBodyBtn).click(function(){
    if($(this).hasClass("btn-active")){
        $(".fad-physician-profile-card-feinstein__column-wrapper").removeClass("active")
    }else{
        $(".fad-physician-profile-card-feinstein__column-wrapper").next().addClass("active")
    }
});
```

If a button is clicked on the first index node, the second index node get "active" class, it should alternate when click on a button in each index.

Wrong behavior:

```
<div id="index0" class="col-sm-9 fad-physician-profile-card-feinstein__column-wrapper"> 
<div id="index1" class="col-sm-9 fad-physician-profile-card-feinstein__column-wrapper active">
```

Expected behavior:

```
<div id="index0" class="col-sm-9 fad-physician-profile-card-feinstein__column-wrapper active"> 
<div id="index1" class="col-sm-9 fad-physician-profile-card-feinstein__column-wrapper">
```

See live codepen: https://codepen.io/paul-solomon/pen/LYVpZvq?editors=1010

Comment: Can you try and explain that again? Also what is $contentBodyBtn?

Comment: You have a button in each section, and you want each button to toggle THAT SECTIONS active class? Instead, the button toggles next sections active class?

Comment: right $contentBodyBtn = $(".fad-btn__toggle"), when its clicked in each section, the active class should alternate when it clicked in each section. in the codepen example it doesn't alternate.

Answer (score 0):

When you are clicking the button, you can use `$(this).closest(". ..")` to find the parent element you want to add or remove `active` class (in this case `fad-physician-profile-card-feinstein__column-wrapper`). That way when you click the button, it will always add/remove active class to that parent **only**.

```
if($contentBody.length >= 0){
           $($contentBodyBtn).click(function(){
              if($(this).hasClass("btn-active")){
                $(this).removeClass("btn-active");
                $(this).text("View more");
                $(this).next($contentBodyArrow).removeClass("caret-up");
                $(this).closest(".fad-physician-profile-card-feinstein__column-wrapper").removeClass("active")
              }else{
                $(this).addClass("btn-active");
                $(this).text("View less");
                $(this).next($contentBodyArrow).addClass("caret-up")
                $(this).closest(".fad-physician-profile-card-feinstein__column-wrapper").addClass("active")
              }
          });
}
```